# Remove all files from (sometimes empty) directory

Tags: bash, rm

In my script I have a command for removing all files from the `www` directory.

```
rm -rf www/*
```

However, in some cases the `www` directory is empty. Then he command and whole script fails.

Is there a  better command I could use that would not fail on empty dir?

EDIT: it would be perfect if the hidden files were not removed, as I want to keep the `.gitkeeep` file. Worst case scenario I can go with `... && touch .gitkeep`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the POSIX `find`:

```
find www -path 'www/[!.]*' -prune -exec rm -r -- {} +
```

By design, find does not fail if no argument is provided. See [example 8 in the specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_17) which makes that clear.

Meaning of the options:

- `-path` specifies that we only look for paths that begin in `www/` and do not have a dot immediately following (so it excludes hidden files from the removal list).
- `-prune` prevents find from trying to descend in directories (you are already using `rm -r`, which does that).
- `--` in `rm -r -- {} +` allows processing of found files even though they start with a hyphen.

Comment: +1 and allowed myself to add `--` to your `rm -r {} +`

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way in *pure bash* (only builtin):

Even if you use

```
set -e
```

to stop the script on a non zero exit error, you can do:

```
shopt -s nullglob # don't treat * literally
shopt -u dotglob  # don't match .dotfiles

rm -rf  www/* 2>/dev/null || true
#             < hide err><       > 
#                      only if set -e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find www -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -r -- {} +
```

If the `.gitkeep` is in the `www` directory then you can do this:

```
find www -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name .gitkeep -exec rm -r -- {} +
```

Comment: Use of the `-mindepth` flag is only warranted, in the case where directory `www` happens not to contain `.gitkeep`. If not, in the absence of the `-mindepth` flag and of `www/.gitkeep`, `www` would be removed by the `rm -r` cmd. So ok, but combining `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` is exactly what `-prune` gives you. Also OP asks to be able to keep all hidden files, so maybe:   `! -name ".*"` ?

Comment: @Cbhihe `www` is not to be removed. And `-prune` does not descend into the command line paths. `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` descends exactly one level.